# My self hosted service doesn´t authenticate a remote client (netTcpBinding, MessageSecurity Basic 128)

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have a self hosted service, it includes an endpoint that uses NetTcpBinding with message level security (Basic128).

**This service can be successfully added and accessed from a client located in the same machine**

But if I build a client in a **remote machine** (over the local network), **I can successfully add the service reference**, but when I try to run it, I get a **SecurityNegotiationException** saying that "**The caller was not authenticated by the service**"

What could It be?

This is the Service model of the service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="metadataSupport">
                <serviceMetadata />
           </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="ProductsServiceTcpBindingConfig">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message algorithmSuite="Basic128" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataSupport" name="Products.ProductsServiceImpl">
            <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProductsServiceTcpBindingConfig"
                name="NetTcp_IProductsService" contract="Products.IProductsService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="MetaDataTcpEndpoint"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8080/Service" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And this the Service Model of the remote client

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcp_IProductsService">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message algorithmSuite="Basic128" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://RemoteServer:8080/Service" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcp_IProductsService" contract="ProductsService.IProductsService"
            name="NetTcp_IProductsService">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="RemoteServer\Rafael" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using spnIdentity? There is a way to do this with a dummy identity.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiche/archive/2011/07/13/wcf-on-intranet-with-windows-authentication-kerberos-or-ntlm-part-1.aspx

Also make sure port 8080 is open.